# Website gets blocked by webfilterproxyd even without website restriction

Tags: web-browsing, proxy, parental-controls

I have a Mac Mini running Mac OS X 10.6.4 which has Parental Controls enabled for an account, but with Website Restrictions set to 'Allow unrestricted access to websites'.

However, there is one website (which I cannot specify for confidentiality reasons) which does not load at all. Instead I get the following error message in the system log every time I try to access the website:

```
sandboxd[12606] <Notice>: webfilterproxyd(712) deny network-inbound 10.1.1.3:49757
```

Obviously 10.1.1.3 is the machine's IP address and 49757 in this case would be the port that the request was sent from.

The website in question is in no way a bad/inappropriate/illegal website, so I don't see why it would be filtered.

Disabling Parental Controls completely for this account fixes the problem, but I'd rather not do that.

Any idea how I can fix this, or why it is happening in the first place?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it can be solved by doing:

```
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/webcontentfilter.kext/
```

This might cause a few errors in the system log but appears to work fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone else stumbles on this as I did...

Deleting *webcontentfilter.kext* is actually deleting part of Parental Controls. `kext` is short for *kernel extension*. It is better to turn Parental Controls off than to wreck it.

What was probably going on is that you need to, in the main firewall (**under Security, in System Preferences**), allow incoming connections from that IP address. You may need to configure the firewall manually, if so, consult a complete tutorial.

Also, `49757` is not the port the request was coming from, it is the local port the request is attempting to connect to.

Answer (score -1):

Yosemite 10.10.5

Before, i suppose that copy/compress this folder should be wiser.

> zip -r /System/Library/Extensions/webcontentfilter.kext.save.zip/ /System/Library/Extensions/webcontentfilter.kext/

then

> sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/webcontentfilter.kext/

Violent, but that's work, thanks !
I have full access to the network with Parental Control