# What does webcontentfilter.kext do?

Tags: macos, kernel-extensions

So I'm learning about writing Kernel Extensions and while I was looking for examples I stumbled across `webcontentfilter.kext`.

I gathered from this post [Website gets blocked by webfilterproxyd even without website restriction](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26430/website-gets-blocked-by-webfilterproxyd-even-without-website-restriction) that it has something to do with Parental Controls, which as a child in his mid-30's, I am whole-heartedly against.

Upon deeper examination, inside the kernel extensions executable `/System/Library/Extensions/webcontentfilter.kext/Contents/MacOS/webcontentfilter` I found the following phrase which gave me pause.

```
`================================
 ======== HolyInquisition =======
 ================================`
```

Without actually disassembling it (I can't disable SIP right now, long story.) it looks like a bunch of functions, name with the prefix `holy_` for creating/filtering/closing sockets, and some hooks to the factory standard macOS programs. Which would make sense for parental controls. Just wondering if this is programmer humor, or if I should throw the MacBook in the water and see if floats.

Also, I would really like to know in as gross detail as possible how `webcontentfilter.kext` works. That would be nice too. It's what I'm here for.

[image]

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: I want to know how it works, in gross detail. My only problem is that I'm insatiably curious. I also want to know how the 'HolyInquisition' library name. That's a pretty intense name for a set of networking functions. Feel free to down vote.

Comment: Your insatiable curiosity is admirable, @knotech, I live my life much the same way. This forum is for asking questions when problems arise with Apple hardware/software that seem intractable, or when personal troubleshooting and experience fail to find an acceptable solution. Are you a member of the [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/)? If not, a wealth of information is available once you join.